# Fish shell not loading in paths from bashrc

Tags: bash, fish

I have a fish shell which does not load the paths from bash when I start it.

I have the following line in my `~/.bashrc`

```sh
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/go/bin
```

When a new fish terminal is opened by default go is not recognised. However, when I switch to bash by running `bash` and then back to fish by running `fish` the paths are loaded in and go works. Is there a way for the paths in the `bashrc` file to be loaded in automatically without me defining them again in fish?

Comment: What is your login shell? Are you sure you are sourcing in `.bashrc` when you log in? If fish is indeed your login shell, why not source in `.bashrc` from `~/.config/fish/config.fish`? See [How to add exports to fish like in .bashrc?](https://askubuntu.com/q/33845/615697) on Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: `fish` and `bash` are two entirely separate shells. There's no *reason* why `fish` would get anything from `.bashrc`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @chepner has rightly pointed out, it is good to keep fish's config.fish independent of .bashrc since these shells use different syntax. If you do need to use .bashrc and limit that script to the syntactic nuances of fish, then try adding this to your `~/.config/fish/config.fish` file:

```
bashrc=$HOME/.bashrc
[ -f "$bashrc" ] && source "$bashrc"
```

Comment: It would be better to set the path explicitly in `config.fish` (assuming `fish` won't inherit `PATH` from another instance of `bash`) than to require `.bashrc` to conform to the subset of code that is valid in both `bash` and `fish`.

Comment: After adding the lines i get the following error `~/.config/fish/config.fish (line 2): Unsupported use of '='. In fish, please use 'set bashrc $HOME/.bashrc'.
from sourcing file ~/.config/fish/config.fish
        called during startup
source: Error while reading file '/home/prnvbn/.config/fish/config.fish'`

Comment: Yes, fish is not bash-compatible, so reading .bashrc will typically not work. The common subset of the two languages is very very small - not even variable definitions or `if` blocks.

Answer (score 0):

A *fishy* way to load in in paths is to just run the following command once.

```sh
set -U fish_user_paths /usr/local/go/bin $fish_user_paths
```

Running this command once is the equivalent of adding the export statement to your `.bashrc` file.

Thank you everyone else for your answers but I feel like this solved my problem the best!