# Node and npm latest version in fish shell

Tags: node.js, linux, shell, npm

I currently faced a problem regarding the version of node and npm in the fish shell.
I was using bash shell for some time and have installed the latest node and npm using nvm on it, and recently shifted to fish, but those latest versions are not available.
please help me with the same. 
Thanks in advance.
OS: Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: did you add them to your $PATH? Also you if added them to your PATH on your .bashrc, and you are not somehow sourcing this from fish, then you won't see them. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69467413/fish-shell-not-loading-in-paths-from-bashrc

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

1. Get your prefix: `npm config get prefix` (e.g. /Users/[username]/.node_modules_global)
2. Add a line with this path plus `/lib` to `.config/fish/config.fish`:
   `set PATH /Users/[username]/.node_modules_global/bin $PATH`
3. Restart Fish terminal and check `npm -v`